# Memcache get optimization with php

Tags: php, optimization, memcached

Okay so I have some weird-er questions about Memcache. The whole basic idea of my caching technique is to save data to be requested by my PHP script in Memcached server. The main issue me and my team faced is that sometimes saving large amounts of data can sometimes pass the 1MB limit for the item data size in Memcached.
To further explain the approach imagine the following:
We have lots of data to configure a certain object and that data contains a lot of text and numbers..etc. And we need to save almost 200 items of those objects so the first approach we went with is to cache the entire 200ish objects to one big item in Memcached. That item may surpass the limit of 1Mb so we figured we can go with a new approach.
The new approach we went with is that we break down the data configuring the object into smaller building blocks (and since we don't use all the data in the same page) we would then use the smaller building blocks to get exactly the amount of data that we would use in that particular page.

The question is as follows:
Does the GET speed change when you get bigger data? Or would the  limitation on the amount of requests handled by Memcached server in parallel get in the way of the second approach because we would then use multi GET to get the multiple building blocks configuring the object?

I know this is a weird question but it's vital to the new approach that we're going with since it would determine the size of the building blocks that we will use and whether or not we will add data to it if we need to.

Edit 1:
Bear in mind that we can use the MULTIGET function with the second approach so we don't have to connect to Memecached and wait for a response for each bit of data that we're getting. So  parallel requests will be used to get the multiple keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without getting into the 'what the heck are you storing in memcache and why not use another solution (like a DB  with a memory table storage engine)....

I'd say the cost of the multiple requests is indeed a concern--especially with memcached running on remote nodes/hosts.  A single request for a large object is most likely overall faster--you still need the same amount of data transferred, but will not have the additional separate request overhead vs. the 200 pieces.

BTW... If you're using APC and you don't have many of these huge items, you can use it instead of memcache to do local user level memory caching--the max size is easily tweakable via the php config settings.  You won't get the benefit of distibuted access/sharing across hosts, but it's fast and simple.

Comment: I would say what he is trying to do will actually be faster this way. Instead of storing a massive single object and fetching a large portion of data that won't be used, the whole thing is calculated once and broken down to what is needed on a page by page basis. That means when he fetches from memcache, he'll only get what he needs (less data), and it is still a single request. I agree with the "what the heck are you storing" though.

Comment: Does it matter what exactly we're storing in memcache? it's some data to identify a database object that we have. I want the speed of memcache for optimization that's all. Let's say that I need items x, y and z for page 1 and items x, y, z, a, b and c for page 2. The whole idea is that I want to save x, y, z in a memcache key and a, b,c in another memcache key. Which is better? This approach or just saving x, y, z, a, b and c in one memcache key and retrieve the whole thing in one request?

Comment: @Bola the single request is going to be more efficient if you always want the entire set of components.

Comment: @hukir His question points to always pulling the entire set of data back, not a subset.

Comment: That's the main issue in question. Is it better to have a MULTIGET for multiple blocks or just one big bulk of data retrieved even if I'm not going to use all of it?

Comment: @Bola depends on the amount of data needed.  Say only 10% of the blocks, then multiple gets would be the way to go. But if you're using the majority of the data, a single would be better.